# Misusing ThreadPoolExecutor - OOM errors

Tags: java

Im reading files from **SQS** in an unbounded stream. As I read each file I want to submit it to a second queue for processing. I can simultaneously process several files so I put these into threads and want to block further reads from the queue when all threads are in use.

To that end I used this:

```
ExecutorService executorService =
   new ThreadPoolExecutor(
       maxThreads, // core thread pool size
       maxThreads, // maximum thread pool size
       1, // time to wait before resizing pool
       TimeUnit.MINUTES,
       new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maxThreads, true),
       new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

Where `maxThreads = 2`.

Files are read in blocks of ten and processed as such:

```
for (Message msg : resp.getMessages()) {
    Gson g = new Gson();

    MessageBody messageBody = g.fromJson(msg.getBody(), MessageBody.class);
    MessageRecords messageRecords = g.fromJson(messageBody.getMessage(), MessageRecords.class);

    List<MessageRecords.Record> records = messageRecords.getRecords();

    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        ... do some work based on file type
        }
    });
```

Watching the thread count Im seeing it climb steadily until the system runs out of memory, closes the job with a **unable to create native thread** exception. After this the VM(AWS) doesn't accept SSH logins until it gets stopped / restarted.

It seems like there must be a step where a given thread is released / cleaned up but Im not seeing where it should happen.

What am I doing wrong?

---

### Edit:

- yes, `run()` does finish and exit
- nothing else interacts with these threads. the `run()` method gets a file, looks at the type and calls a fn() based on the type. Function parses the file and returns. Then `run()` is finished.

Comment: Does `run` ever finish?

Comment: I'd be looking at it in a debugger to find out what all those threads are doing.  If `maxThreads` really is `2`, then it's hard to imagine that they are pool worker threads.  Are you certain that something else that you call isn't creating them?

Comment: Have you tried doing something simple like `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`? If it still blows up even after that, then it would seem like you're somehow creating multiple services without closing them, or spawning new threads elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is my use of `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Specifically where it appear(s/ed) in the app process. I was creating a new thread pool for each loop through a block of SQS messages and not closing it afterwards. Moving this creation *outside* the loop and reusing the same block fixes the problem.

So - a big hairy UFU.